# JQuery AJAX Method Returns a Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have been wrestling with a weird error for quite some time now. I want to believe that this is one of those errors where the solution will just slap me in the face, but we shall see. Here's the code:

```
    var images = {};
    // Set Image Gallery
    function setImageGallery() {
        // Get Product JSON
        $.ajax({
            url:"JSONimages.php"
            data:{
                "table":"belts"
            }, // Firefox says this } is missing... but it's here.
            success:function (data) {
                images = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert("Got Images!");
            }
        });
    }
```

And here's the code snippet being pulled from an AJAX Request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setImageGallery($("select[name=imageGallerySelect]").val().toLowerCase());
</script>

<h2>Edit Image Gallery</h2>
<p>Select Gallery: <select name="imageGallerySelect" onchange="setImageGallery()">
    <option>Belts</option>
    <option>Gallery</option>
    <option>Home</option>
    <option>Hybrid</option>
    <option>IWB</option>
    <option>Knives</option>
    <option>OWC</option>
</select></p>
<form action="">
    <p>Image:<br><input type="file" name="image"></p>
    <p>Price:<br><input type="text" name="price"></p>
    <p>Description:<br><textarea name="description"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save"></p>
    <div id="thumbnails"></div>
</form>
```

Now, in the process of debugging, I changed the $.AJAX() method to directly set the value of "table" for my PHP (which outputs JSON) script to "belts". I'm getting mixed results. Chrome is telling me it's an error from the JQuery Script itself. Firefox says there's a missing "}" at the spot where I put the little comment in the first code sample. I've toyed with the script with zero luck. It's errors like this that let me know I have a lot to learn :/
The anonymous success function never gets run and the alert doesn't pop up, of course. I'm hoping this is a stupid error and that I'm making a newb mistake here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **,** after the `url` parameter:

```
 url:"JSONimages.php", //<-------------- this comma you missed
            data:{
                "table":"belts"
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh god, I saw it as soon as I submitted the question. The function setImageGallery() does not accept any variables, but I pass it a string!

Answer (score 0):

Wait, no. That was a stupid mistake, but I'm still getting an error. Help? Firefox error reads: "SyntaxError: missing } after property list". Chrome insists that the error is on Line 2 of the JQuery Library. I don't know that either of those errors are very useful. The } is there. The JQuery library is flawless. I want to believe that I'm somehow screwing up the $.ajax() call, but it worked when I used it elsewhere.